# Adding padding to Angular UI modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fxQjevliFcy3iZW2OBNw?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal containing a table. I want to add a margin between the table borders and the modal borders, but declaring in the css a `padding` element does not work. How to achieve this?

Also, I need the modal width to expand automatically depending on the content width. Is this possible?

HTML

```
    <style>
      .app-modal .modal-dialog {
          min-width: 260px;
          padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">The Title</h4>
    </div>

    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>333</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

 </script>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope,$uibModal) {

          $scope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              windowClass: 'app-modal',
            }); 


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add padding to the class *.modal-content* instead

```
.app-modal .modal-content{
   padding: 10px;
}
```